# JSF Deploy Error "at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)"

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere

I want to deploy an enterprise project on Websphere.

I got the following exception.

What can be the reason?

```
[03.09.12 11:21:05:636 CEST] 0000001a webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.getEntry(ThreadLocal.java:371)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:254)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:138)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:293)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
    at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.isProcessingEvents(FacesContext.java:300)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stacktrace [suggests](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-api/2.1.8/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.java#291) that you're using MyFaces and that at some point before in the code the `FacesContext.setCurrentInstance(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())` is been invoked which would result in this kind of infinite loop.

That's all I can tell based on the information provided so far. I'm not sure why the current instance of the faces context is been set with the current instance. Perhaps it's a bug in your own code, or something is wrongly configured. Verify the classpath for pollution (duplicate older versioned JARs) and verify any startup code (`Filter#init()`, `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized()`, etc) if it isn't doing some weird stuff.

Comment: You're welcome, but have you been able to naildown the cause and find the solution? If so, please tell about the cause and the solution as well, so that others may have benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I checked my code. Everything was ok. I use MyEclipse 10.5. I thought it can be configuration problem. But actually it was a bug in Myeclipse. I updated to version 10.6. Now everything works.